# How to join result from 2 tables

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, microsoft-metro

I've got class:

```
public class FeedData
{
    private List<FeedItem> _Items = new List<FeedItem>();
    public List<FeedItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Items;
        }
    }
}

public class FeedDataSource
{
    private ObservableCollection<FeedData> _Feeds = new ObservableCollection<FeedData>();
    public ObservableCollection<FeedData> Feeds
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Feeds;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do my code smaller so I try to use `LINQ`, but I just don't have any idea how to do this.
Here is my code

```
private static FeedData GetFeedFromDatabase(string feedLink)
{
    FeedData feedData = new FeedData();
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(Application.Current.Resources["DbPath"].ToString()))
    {
        var matches = db.Table<FeedData>().Where(feed => feed.Link.Equals(feedLink));
        if (matches.Any())
        {
            feedData = matches.Single();
            feedData.Items.AddRange(
                                        db.Table<FeedItem>().
                                        Where(item => item.FeedId.Equals(feedData.Id))
                                    );
        }
    }

    return feedData;
}
```

I don't want to use AddRange, I would like to use as little as possible `LINQ` expression to get data from `FeedData` table and `FeedItem` table. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because there is no public setter for `FeedData.Items`.  Without the setter you must rely on the methods provided by the `List` class to modify the list.

If you had a setter you could simply assign the list:

```
public List<FeedItem> Items {
  get { return _Items; }
  set { _Items = value; }
}

feedData.Items = db.Table<FeedItem>()
                   .Where(item => item.FeedId = feedData.Id).ToList();
```